# Change the icon picture

Tags: jquery, css

If you have the cursor over the textbox, the icon should be changing into a computer (the picture that I have uploaded) and if you have the cursor outside of the bluelight background, it should be turned into a airplane.

I don't know how to do it.

```js
$(".delete-tag").click(function() {

  $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

```css
.delete-tag {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.delete-tag:hover,
.delete-tag-active {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/24/silhouette5-16.png"), none;
  background-size: initial;
}
.delete-tag {
  background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/22/airplane1-16.png');
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.post-tag {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #3e6d8e;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #e4edf4;
  border: 1px solid #e4edf4;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -o-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  padding: .4em .5em;
}
.post-tag:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3e6d8e;
  background-color: #dae6ef;
  border: 1px solid #dae6ef;
  background-color: #DAE6EF;
}
```

```html
<span class="post-tag">
   aasdfas
   <span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
</span>



<span class="post-tag">
   basdfasdf
   <span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
</span>

<span class="post-tag">
   basdfasdf
   <span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
</span>


<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/24/laptop1-16.png" />
```

Please take account that you have many post-tag. If you have 3 post-tag and I want remove only one, not all.

Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/nfsqoazq/2/

Comment: Put your default background declaration before your hover declaration. Your CSS is a mess in general. All of the default stuff should be in the first block (why is .delete-tag listed twice and overriding itself)?

Comment: I need to do a factoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the icon change when you hover the `.post-tag` element, use the following css:

```
.post-tag:hover .delete-tag,
.post-tag:active .delete-tag {
    background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/24/silhouette5-16.png"), none;
    background-size: initial;
}
```

**EDIT**

```js
$(".delete-tag").click(function() {

  $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

```css
.delete-tag {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.post-tag:hover .delete-tag, /* edit */
.delete-tag-active {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/24/laptop1-16.png"), none;
  background-size: initial;
}
.post-tag:hover .delete-tag:hover, /* edit */
.delete-tag {
  background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/24/silhouette5-16.png');
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.post-tag {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #3e6d8e;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #e4edf4;
  border: 1px solid #e4edf4;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  -o-transition: color .15s ease, background .15s ease, border .15s ease;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  padding: .4em .5em;
}
.post-tag:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3e6d8e;
  background-color: #dae6ef;
  border: 1px solid #dae6ef;
  background-color: #DAE6EF;
}
```

```html
<span class="post-tag">
   aasdfas
   <span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
</span>



<span class="post-tag">
   basdfasdf
   <span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
</span>

<span class="post-tag">
   basdfasdf
   <span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span>
</span>


<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gcons-2/24/laptop1-16.png" />
```

Comment: Yes, I tried. I see that when I hover the icon, the icon changes, but when I hover the text, nothing happens. You want to have the icon change when you hover the text, right? Or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: "You want to have the icon change when you hover the text, right?"  Both for the text and the box except the icon (+ symbol).

Comment: If it possible can you apply a solution with function code snippet?

Comment: When the cursor of on the text or the blue frame, the icon will be not changed into a computer.

Comment: It is almost correct. When you have the mouse over the blueframe and the text, it is correct but if you have the cursor over the icon, a human face shouid appear. So tottaly there are three different icon

Comment: Ah, I got confused. Just change the icon to a human face icon and you're good to go. I'll update my answer.